# File Count: performant options

Tags: windows, memory, windows-server-2008-r2

I help handle our backup solution at work. Many servers. Many OSs. I've recently come across a server that I'm now backing up.

The main issue with this server is the fact that it has millions of files. At least 41 million, but likely somewhere in the neighborhood of 60 million.

I'm trying to find quick and resource easy options to track how many files are on the server and how many have changed in a given time frame.

I normally use [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.info/) for basic information. It does a great job of visualizing what files are where. The issue seems to be that it takes forever and uses a ton of memory. I stopped it a short way through and it had already gobbled up ~600mb of memory. Normally it takes awhile, but it also normally doesn't have to iterate through ~60 million files.

I'm trying [Folders Report](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/folrep.html) now. It seems to be much easier on the memory usage (~5mb atm and should be at least half way through the information gathering). The issue, is that it's taking forever and I'm not sure if it's going to have the number of files changed in the last 24 hours (or ability to find that nugget of information).

I can log into the system, but don't wish to mess with the software being run on the server (Oracle, custom apps, etc). What can I do to get the desired information fast, without being a resource hog? what are some other good options to get information like raw file counts and files recently modified?

Some other tool? Command line script? PowerShell (Tried `(Get-ChildItem ..).Count` and ran into memory issues)? Perl?

(Not sure if this question is tagged well. Feel free to suggest better tags or re-tag if you have the ability)

Comment: Thanks for the comment about the close vote... I'd sure love to make the changes you suggested.

Comment: Rsync??????????

Comment: @qasdfdsaq Windows generally doesn't have rsync and I'd prefer not to have to install anything... but does rsync have information gathering parts? file counts and "what was modified yesterday" type questions? I hadn't considered rsync since this is Windows based, but I might have the same question on linux machines - and if it is a good option I might consider installing cygwin to try it on windows.

Comment: Well you've already installed WinDirStat and Folders Report, I'd assume a well-known and trusted open-source tool shouldn't be a problem. Admittedly the Windows port isn't as robust but still has the "dry-run" option that just lists modified files. That said if you just want to *list* files and not do any backup or copying, just a few Cygwin scripts or Powershell scripts should be able to do that

Comment: Well the desire is to do it with a bare minimum of changing the system. WinDirStat is much more "minimum" than cygwin lol. I've tried powershell, but it seems to eat memory with the few attempts I've done (one listed in edited question). I've got people telling me "these folders don't change" - which makes me want to do one thing - but I've got suspicions that those folder do change - which means I need to do something else. But the tools I normally use (like WDS) take too long and/or eat too much memory for quick queries.

Comment: For example, the listed Folders Report program I tried gives all the file counts but takes hours (4? maybe 5?) to finish. It doesn't have search for stuff that changed yesterday. I'd be okay if the data took an hour to run... or two hours and I could do daily checks on whats changing for the last few days. It's hard to plan backups on an outlier system when the info provided to me is suspect. I hope I'm making sense. And the exact file count last night was ~59.5 million files. This morning it was ~56.6.